# Decomposition of functions

Tags: functions

I have a question regarding decomposition of functions.

Suppose I have a continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=f(1)$.

How do I show that $f$ can be decomposed into two continuous functions $g$ and $h$,

such that $f=g+h$,

where $g$ and $h$ are defined for $x\in[0,1/2]$ such that $g(x)=g(1-x)$, $h(x)=-h(1-x)$

and $h(0)=h(1/2)=0$.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that $f=g+h$, and that you extend the definitions of $g$ and $h$ from $[0,1/2]$ to all of $[0,1]$ using the indicated symmetries?

Comment: Oh yes f=g+h. I now edit the question.

Comment: Try calculating $f(x)+f(1-x)$ in terms of $g$ and $h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't the combinations $\frac{f(x)\pm f(1-x)}{2}$ do the job? Use "$+$" for $g$ and "$-$" for $h$.